# What are some of the resources to learn practical issues in machine learning and data science?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I feel like a lot of the resources on ML have been focused on algorithms/modeling whereas in practice (industry applications) what's arguably the harder part, IMO, is what's before and after modeling (collecting unbiased training data, error diagnosis, conduct appropriate A/B testing, explore/exploit, etc) What are some of the resources to learn these practical issues in ML/DS ? Is experimental design the right keyword?